# How to fix "Could not find class file for 'jnu'."

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm doing mathematical calculation using Java native interfaces, but when i tried it to execute on terminal it shows me following error.

kiran@kiran-X510UNR:~$ javac jnu.java

kiran@kiran-X510UNR:~$ javah -jni jnu

Error: Could not find class file for 'jnu'.

```
public native int add(int n1,int n2);
public native int sub(int n1,int n2);
public native int mul(int n1,int n2);
public native int div(int n1,int n2);

public static void main(String a[])
{
    jnu tj = new jnu();

    int ch,n1,n2;
    Scanner sh = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter two numbers ");
    n1 = sh.nextInt();
    n2 = sh.nextInt();      

    System.out.println("\n1.Add\n2.Sub\n3.Mul\n4.Div");
    ch = sh.nextInt();

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Addition is : "+tj.add(n1,n2));break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Subtraction is : "+tj.sub(n1,n2));break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Multiplication is : "+tj.mul(n1,n2));break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Division is : "+tj.div(n1,n2));break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong choice");break;
    }       
}

static
{
    System.loadLibrary("jnu");
}
```

test.c

...

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jnu_add(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,jint n1,jint n2)
{
    return n1+n2;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jnu_sub(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,jint n1,jint n2)
{
    return n1-n2;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jnu_mul(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,jint n1,jint n2)
{
    return n1*n2;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jnu_div(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,jint n1,jint n2)    
{    
    return n1/n2;        
}
```

...

I expect header file should be generated, but error shows could not find class for jnu.

Comment: Your code is not readable, please format it correctly.

Comment: It works for me (assuming that you have a `public class jnu {`). This also assumes that you haven't specified a package name. If you _do_ have a package name, you need to take this into account. For example, if you have `package foo.bar;`, then jnu.java should be located in `foo/bar/`, and after running `javac foo/bar/jnu.java` you should run `javah -jni foo.bar.jnu`